# Unit Testing AngularJS Directives: scopes not updating?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

**Short version:** I have a directive that is using a "new scope" (i.e., `scope:true`; *not* an isolate scope) which appears to work just fine when I'm interacting with the application, but which does not appear to update the `scope` in an observable way in the unit tests. **Why are the changes to `field` on the directive's scope *not* observable in the unit test?**

Example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gpzHsX?p=preview

Here's the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('ngxBlurry', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict:'C',
      replace:false,
      scope:true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('blur', function() {
          var val = element.val();
          scope.$apply(function(scope) {
            scope.field = val;
          });
        });

        scope.$watch('field', function(n, o) {
          if (n !== o) {
            scope.fields[n] = scope.fields[o];
            delete scope.fields[o];
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

It's getting used roughly as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="FooContoller">
  <div ng-repeat="(field, value) in fields">
    <input value="{{field}}" type="text" class="ngx-blurry"/>
    <strong>"field" is &laquo;{{field}}&raquo;</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming that `fields` looks something approximately like:

```
$scope.fields = {
  'foo':true,
  'bar':true,
  'baz':true,
  '':true
};
```

And here's the unit test:

```
describe('ngxBlurry', function() {
  var scope,
      element,
      template = '<input value="{{field}}" type="text" class="ngx-blurry"/>';

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.fields = {'foo':true, '':true};
    scope.field = '';

    element = $compile(template)(scope);
  }));

  it('defers update until after blur', function() {
    spyOn(scope, '$apply');

    element.val('baz');
    element.triggerHandler('blur');

    // true:
    expect(scope.$apply).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // false!?
    expect(scope.field).toBe('baz');

    scope.$digest();
    // still false:
    expect(scope.field).toBe('baz');

    element.scope().$digest();
    // *still* false:
    expect(scope.field).toBe('baz');
    // also false:
    expect(element.scope().field).toBe('baz');
  });
});
```

Now, when interacting with the application:

1. I can type into the `input` and any updates to the keys in `$scope.fields` are deferred until the blur event on that field.
2. In the test, the Jasmine spy is reporting that the call to `$apply` is happening *but*...
3. ...the function that should be executed within the context of that `$apply` is (apparently) not getting called.
4. ...nor does the `$watch` expression get called.

The directive itself in the context of the running application appears to operate just fine, but I cannot seem to find any reason why I cannot observe the changes with a unit test.

Barring a redesign of the directive (e.g., to use isolate scope and `$emit` events): is there anything that I have missed here? Something I should change about the directive? or else some trick to make these changes observable in the unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell: **don't forget `.andCallThrough()` on the spy.**

Changing nothing about the directive itself, the working version of the test needed to be:

```
// everything about the `describe` stays the same...
it('defers update until after blur', function() {
  spyOn(scope, '$apply').andCallThrough();

  element.val('baz');
  element.triggerHandler('blur');

  expect(scope.$apply).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(element.scope().field).toBe('baz');
});
```

So...

1. The Jasmine `spy` needed `andCallThrough()`
2. Use `element.scope()` to access the correct scope.